# Inside my PnP Search Result web part, how i can show the Term title instead of the Term GUID

Tags: search, administration, term-store, managed-property, pnp-search-webparts

I have a site column of typed managed metadata named `ContactCustomerName`, which is linked to a term set. and inside our PnP Search Result web part i am showing the value of the related managed metadata named `owstaxIdContactCustomerName`, as follow:-

[image]

but what i am getting is the term GUID and not the user friendly Term title, as follow:-

[image]

any advice on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the GUID since you have defined that in the column value "owsTaxIdXxxxxx" (note the ID part of the property). So you need that column in the search result to a property with the friendly name/value of the managed metadata.

I would recommend creating a managed property in the search schema (guide:
https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-a-managed-property-in-sharepoint-online/) and use that in your search result web part.

Otherwise you could use the debug feature of the PnP web part, and check out which properties the search results have and see if you could use any of those for your purpose.

[image]

Comment: but is there a crawl property which stores the term tile which i can map to a refinable managed property?

Comment: Yes, there is. If you have access to the search schema (found here: https://<your-domain>-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/searchadmin/ta_listcrawledproperties.aspx?level=tenant) you can search for display name of the field and you should see the crawled properties. Most likely there is one called ows_ContactCustomerName that can be mapped to a refinablestring :) Then you can filter on that managed property.